# How to automate SVG "g" elements alignment using transform in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg

I made a simple logo builder in Node.JS to render SVG logos made of an icon and a text string. The output is simply a SVG string containing the rendered icon and text, wrapped in two separate `<g>` tags.

I'm trying to use SVG transform matrix to change the layout of the result, for example to move the icon over the text or to move it on the right, but I can't find a tool (npm package? vanilla js?) to do that.

Here's an example of a transformation I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Are there solutions to this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: it would be useful to see what some output code looks like

Comment: ...and what you have already tried (if anything).  The place you should start is by calling the `getBBox()` method on each of those group elements.  That will give you the position and width of each. From there it is just some trivial math to work out the new position(s).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown any of your code? Im a front-end developer and I currently use D3 and SVG.

Have you thought of using D3?

It would be something like this:

You use .data('this.nodes') to choose all of your image elements, or however you wish to group them, and then append a paragraph to each one, and simply align the paragraph to that logo. (you will have to change the names to what you specifically need, but this would do the trick, just look up how d3 works and selections.
https://github.com/d3/d3-selection

```
  addText(): void {
    this.group
      .selectAll('foreignObject')
      .data(this.nodes, node => node)
      .enter()
      .append('foreignObject')
      .attr('class', 'Engagement-GraphNodeLabel')
      .attr('x', 0) // around here you align the text to the current picture
      .attr('y', 0) // around here you align the text to the current picture
      .attr('width', node => this.labelWidth)  //whatever you want
      .attr('height', node => this.nodeHeight(node)) //whatever you want
      .append('xhtml:div')
      .html(node => {

        if (node) {
        return `<p>${node.name}</p>`; //whatever names you want for them (store them `in array format)`
      });
  }
```

The short story of it is, your logos are all stored in 'this.nodes' and called in using .data, then you create a 'foreignobject' on each one, which allows you to assign a paragraph and align it to it, and this will automate it for each one. This assumes you have actually placed the logos on the canvas somewhere already.

You can also use .text instead of .html.

There is another method I have used where I used a table and assigned the text to each table data, aligning with the logos, if you required further help, but both work.